# How to create column in pandas dataframe based on boolean expression and relationship of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df, with columns 'a', 'b', and 'c'. I want to create column 'd' with the conditions on each row:

```
if type(a) != str:
    df['d'] = df['a']
else:
    df['d'] = df['b']/df['c']
```

Some values in 'a' are strings, and some are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where`

```
a_is_str = df['a'].apply(lambda x: s is not str)


df['d'] = np.where(a_is_str, df['a'], df['b']/df['c'])
```

Here is another way you could do it with `apply`:

```
def check_if_str(row):
    if isinstance(row['a'], str):
        return row['a']
    return row['b'] / row['c']

df['d'] = df.apply(check_if_str, axis=1)
```

Comment: I think you might have mixed up the order of the two possibilities in the `where`, but I got what I needed with: `df['d'] =  np.where(df['a'].apply(lambda x: type(x) != str), df['a'], df['b']/df['b'])`. Thank you.

Comment: @slothish1 you're dividing `b` by itself in your comment ^_^

Comment: `df['d'] = np.where(df['a'].apply(lambda x: type(x) != str), df['a'], df['b']/df['c'])` done!

Comment: @Wen How would you approach this problem?